# C# ASP.NET MVC error sharing model between parent and child view using Html.RenderPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, childviews, html.renderpartial

While invoking `@Html.RenderPartial("_ChildPartialView")`, I am getting the following error :

> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' has no applicable method named 'ElementAt' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax

**_Testpaper.cshtml** parent view:

```
    for (i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count;i++)
    {
        ViewBag.QuestionNumber = i;
        Html.RenderPartial("_QuestionDetail"); //Line causing error
    }
```

**_QuestionDetail.cshtml** child view:

```
@model StandardVBA.ViewModels.AssessmentModel
<tr style="padding:4px 0px; background-color:lightskyblue; font-weight:bold;font-family:Cambria;">
    <td style="text-align:left;">
        Q @(ViewBag.QuestionNumber + 1) &nbsp @Model.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).Question
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        ( @Model.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).Marks )
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="questions">
        <ol type="A">
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).QuestionDetails.Count; j++)
            {
                <li>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).QuestionDetails.ElementAt(j).IsSelected)
                    </div>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).QuestionDetails.ElementAt(j).Choice)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions.ElementAt(ViewBag.QuestionNumber).QuestionDetails.ElementAt(j).IsCorrect)
                </li>
            }
        </ol>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I also want to know: why it is mandatory to specify the `@Model` in the child-view when the child-view shares the same model in a `RenderPartial` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model to the child partial view like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count;i++)
{
    ViewBag.QuestionNumber = i;
    Html.RenderPartial("_QuestionDetail", Model.Questions[i]); //Line causing error
}
```

Ensure that the type of **Model.Questions[i]** matches with the model declaration in the child partial view "**@model StandardVBA.ViewModels.AssessmentModel**" otherwise you will get the runtime error.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not passing model to you child view, and using the @model in the child view so fix it by passing the model to your child view like this

```
    for (i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count;i++)
    {
        ViewBag.QuestionNumber = i;
        Html.RenderPartial("_QuestionDetail", Model); //Line causing error
    }
```

secondly you are using  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Questions.......) in your detail view which is your child view, so you need to declare @model...... to use model in your views.

hope this will work!